# Search for all instances of certain annotation type

Tags: java, annotations

Suppose I have this annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface  Name 
{
    String value();
}
```

This is going to be used as follows

```
@Name("name1")
public static Foo foo = new Foo();
```

I have multiples of these across my project source files. Is there an fairly simple way to search and collect all those "foo"s that're preceded by `@Name`?
In other words, I'd like to write a method that would return a `Set<Foo>` containing these.

Thanks!!!

Comment: In java? Using unix cmd line should be pretty easy using find + grep

Comment: @user1291492, the retention is RUNTIME.  The method may or may not have access to the source code.  OTH, maybe the class file is greppable.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but why do you want a `Set<Foo>`.  It would seem to make more sense to have a `Map<String,Foo>` or what is the point of the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really familiar with the classpath scanners that others are suggesting.  They seem like a robust - if not ideal - solution.

If you have control over the source, then you could use annotation processing.

Create an annotation processor that will create a class - `MapClass` with a static member `Map<String,Foo>`.  Every time the annotation processor encounters the @Name annotation, it adds that to the source code of `MapClass`.  When it finishes processing the annotations, it will have the same effect as if you hard coded the map.

Annotation processing happens during compile time.  If some of the classes in your project are not compiled by you.  For example, if someone else compiles some classes and gives a jar to you, then it won't work as easily.  But if all the classes are compiled by you then it should not be a problem.

To create an annotation processor, extend [`AbstractProcessor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html).  You will want to annotate your class with a [`@ SupportedAnnotationTypes ( "Name" )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/SupportedAnnotationTypes.html) annotation (make sure name is the fully qualified name of your annotation.

Override the [`process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#process%28java.util.Set,%20javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment%29) method.  `process` has two parameters:  `annotations` and `roundEnv`.  `annotations` is just the set of annotations that this particular processor supports - in your case it should be (Name).  `roundEnv` is a useful utility class.

Iterate through the one annotation in `annotations`.  Use `roundEnv` to [`getElementsAnnotatedWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html#getElementsAnnotatedWith%28javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement%29).  This should give you the set of all elements that carry the `@Name` annotation.

`AbstractProcessor` has another utility member - [`processingEnv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#processingEnv).  Use its [`getFiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment.html#getFiler%28%29) method to [`createSourceFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html#createSourceFile%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20javax.lang.model.element.Element...%29).

Then you have to modify your compilation a little bit.  You must compile your processor separately and before the other classes.  After the processor is compiled and you are compiling the other classes you must tell the compiler about your processor.  If you are using the command line you would add `-processorpath /path/to/processor/class[es]` and `-processor qualified.name.of.processor`.

The advantages of this approach over the class path scanner is that everything happens at compile time.  So for example, if you accidentally add a `@Name` annotation to a `Bar` element, then you can have the processor throw a compile time error (if you wish the processor can ignore it).  Then you can fix it before the product ships.  With a class path scanner, any error thrown is a run time error - which the user will see.

The disadvantage of this approach is also that everything happens at compile time.  This makes it harder to dynamically add classes to the project.

Comment: This sounds like what I need. But what exactly would the annotation processor look like? And I'm not sure how it can "encounter" the @Name annotation? Wouldn't it still need to do some scanning to find those?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: @user1064918 I hope that helps.  I think the big difference is that the class path scanner is more robust - it will just work.  But if your project is suitable, using an annotation processor may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Classpath scanner. I have used [Metapossum Scanner](https://bitbucket.org/stevevls/metapossum-scanner) (it won out because it is in the mvn repo) to scan for annotated Classes, but I do not think it would scan for annotated Fields.

The other option I looked into was [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/). I have not used Reflections, only researched it. The documentation has a `getFieldsAnnotatedWith` query that seems like what you need.

Be forewarned, the Classpath scanners are slooow and get slooower the more you have in your Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

No not really (not from code).
A solution would be to put them all in a class, and then iterate on the `Field`s (`getFields()`) of the class and check for `Annotation`s (`getAnnotation()`)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/)! It may solve your problem!!!

> Scannotation is a Java library that creates an annotation database from a set of .class files. This database is really just a set of maps that index what annotations are used and what classes are using them.

PS.: [VRaptor framework](http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/en) uses it internally!